# Remove XML attribute using JDOM API?

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I have a JDOM element like the following

**Example:XML(JDOM Element)**

```
<Details>
<Uniqueno>11111</Uniqueno>
<ROWSET name="Persons">
<ROW num="1">
<Name>60821894</Name>
<Age>938338789</Age>
</ROW>
<ROW num="2">
<Name>60821894</Name>
<Age>938338789</Age>
</ROW>
</ROWSET>
</Details>
```

I want to convert like:

```
<Details>
<Uniqueno>11111</Uniqueno>

<ROW num="1">
<Name>60821894</Name>
<Age>938338789</Age>
</ROW>
<ROW num="2">
<Name>60821894</Name>
<Age>938338789</Age>
</ROW>

</Details>
```

**note:ROWSET element is removed**

I want to remove the element using JDOM API?

Comment: Rowset is not an attribute. It's an element. In order to remove it, you'll have to first save all of its content somewhere to restore it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you already tried ?

1. Find the `Details` tag (which is the document root)
2. Find the `ROWSET` tag
3. for each `ROW` tag in `ROWSET` call the `detach()` method on the node and `append()` this detached node to the `Details` tag.
4. Delete the `ROWSET` tag.

With some sample code:

```
// 1
Element details = doc.getRootElement();
// 2
Element rowset = details.getChild("ROWSET");
// 3
for (Element row: rowset.getChildren()) {
    Element r = row.detach();
    details.appendChild(r);
}
// 4
details.removeChild(rowset);
```

Not tested, for more info check the [JDOM API](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JDOM 2.0.x you can do something like:

```
for (Element rowset : details.getChildren("ROWSET")) {
    rowset.detach();
    for (Content c : rowset.getContent()) {
         details.addContent(c.detach());
    }
}
```

If you are using JDOM 1.x you can do something similar, but with more casts....

Comment: Thanks for the above postings,but I am still not able to detach(remove) using JDOM 1.x using detach or remove.How come I remove in version 1.x's?

Comment: you can detach in 1.x, you just have to have the right casts... http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs.1.1/org/jdom/Content.html#detach%28%29